# Disable button on a userForm

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm trying to figure out how to disable a button within my userForm if a certain cell within my spreadsheet equals a certain number.  I tried the code stated below, but it isn't working.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Label2 = Sheets("DATA").Range("AM2").Value
Label4 = Sheets("DATA").Range("AO2").Value
Label7 = Format(Sheets("DATA").Range("R8").Value, "Currency")

If Sheets("DATA").Range("AL10").Value = 10 Then
ActiveSheet.Shapes("CommandButton1").Select
UserFormact_Upgrade.CommandButton1.Enabled = False

Else


End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code should be working, as you're on the right path.

To test it, simply create a new form and add this code, you'll see it should work. Maybe you're having problems within the IF clause?

Besides, you don't need to select the shape prior to disabling it; just disable it right away.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    CommandButton1.Enabled = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but got to this thread trying to solve my problem, and found a solution that wasn't mentioned here. So in case someone gets here like I did, and this didn't quite get them where they needed to go, I thought this might help.

I had a userform with a drop down box called cmdADAMFields, and I didn't want my submit button called FieldsSubmitButton to be enabled until I selected something from the dropdown box.

I had to break up my argument into two different private subs vs one larger If-Then-Else statement.

First, I put:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
If cmbADAMFields.ListIndex = -1 Then FieldsSubmitButton.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

Then when for my pulldown's private sub when it's value changed I wrote:

```
Private Sub cmbADAMFields_Change()
FieldsSubmitButton.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper place for setting  **Enabled** property is in **Activate** event (associated with **Show** method) and not **Initialize** event (associated with **Load** instruction).
The below code disable the button *CommandButton1* when AL10 cell >= 10.

```
        Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
           CommandButton1.Enabled = ( Sheets("DATA").Range("AL10") < 10 )
        End Sub
```

For buttons you can choose between *normal buttons* (property **Enabled**=False and property **Visible**=true), *disabled buttons* (property **Enabled**=False and property **Visible**=true) and *invisible buttons* (property **Enabled**=False and property **Visible**=False), that it is a cleaner interface, in most cases.

Concerning text boxes, besides *normal*, *disabled* and *invisible* status, there is a *locked* status, that is enabled and visible, but cannot be user edited. (property **Locked** = True)

A locked control only can be changed by VBA code. For instance, someone can includes date text boxes, that it's filled using a secondary popup date form with Calendar control.